# Change Checkbox Opacity in Style not working

Tags: wpf, checkbox, opacity

I have a disabled `CheckBox` that I want to change the `Opacity` through a `Style` when `IsChecked` is `True`.

Issue: `Opacity` is not changing.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked"
                        Value="False" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="CheckBox.Opacity"
                                Value="1.0" />
                   </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


<CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

Comment: It's the brush that changes rather than opacity when isenabled false. Change the template to avoid that. If they're system brushes used, you could instead override their value in resources for your checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the Opacity to 1.0 (100% opaque), which is the default.  That is why you don't see any change when the checkbox is checked.  If you set your value to something between 0.0 and 1 (0.5 for example), you'll see the opacity change when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Don't forget that the CheckBox IsEnabled is false, that makes the opaque less than 1. I'm trying to bring it back to 1.0

Comment: Ah, I see, that's a different issue than what I understood you to be asking.  When IsEnabled is false, the opacity is still 1.  What changes are the values on the controls making up the checkbox's `ControlTemplate`.  You could override that template to make the checkbox look the way you want it to when it's disabled.